# how to write inline code in <Target Name="AfterBuild"> in VisualStudio.csproj

Tags: visual-studio, build, msbuild, gruntjs

if $(ConfigurationName) doesn't work in `<AfterBuild>`

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release (
    <Exec Command="grunt karma:unit --no-color &gt; grunt-karma-output.txt" IgnoreExitCode="true" />
    <Exec Command="type grunt-karma-output.txt" CustomErrorRegularExpression=".*mPhantomJS.*FAILED" IgnoreExitCode="false" />
)
</Target Name="AfterBuild">
```

if $(ConfigurationName) WORKS in `<PostBuildEvent>`

```
<PostBuildEvent>
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release (
    <Exec Command="grunt karma:unit --no-color &gt; grunt-karma-output.txt" IgnoreExitCode="true" />
    <Exec Command="type grunt-karma-output.txt" CustomErrorRegularExpression=".*mPhantomJS.*FAILED" IgnoreExitCode="false" />
)
</PostBuildEvent>
```

Could anyone suggest how to check if the build is in release mode in `AfterBuild`?

Answer (score 8):

Use a Condition on the target:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition="$(Configuration)==Release">
  <Exec Command="echo AfterBuild"/>
</Target>
```

Btw this also works the same way for the PostBuildEvent (and the code you posted definitely does *not* work).

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="$(Configuration)==Release">
  <PostBuildEvent>echo PostBuild</PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: how to add a inline if else command within <Target> </Target>
Eg: <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    if ($(Configuration)==Release) {
   <Exec Command="grunt karma:release"> 
 }
    else{ 
   <Exec Command="grunt karma:debug"> 
   }

Comment: You can't. MSbuild isn't a programming language. But what you ask is equivalent to `<Target Name="AfterBuild"><Exec Command="grunt karma:$(Configuration)"/></Target>`.

Comment: Gururaj, the Condition attribute can be a member of the Exec MsBuild task as well as a Target, so you'd use the inverse of the condition on the second inline task where your "else" comes into play.